# Como guardar como HTML data de wp_editor de wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy creando un pequeño plugin, y estoy usando wp_editor como metabox, funciona bien, lo único es que al guardar la información, no conserva el marcado HTML y me devuelve todo como texto plano, y necesito mostrar la información tal como el usuario la haya introducido, es decir, si guardo una lista (li) o un enlace (a) pues en el front debo mostrar una lista o un enlace etc.
Dejo algunas capturas, tanto del código que estoy usando como del editor.

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida, muchas gracias!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) : die;
endif;

if (!class_exists('Wp_editor_class')) :

    class Wp_editor_class
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            add_action('add_meta_boxes', [$this, 'we_add_wp_editor']);
            add_action('save_post', [$this, 'we_save_mb']);
        }

        public function we_add_wp_editor()
        {
            add_meta_box(
                'citation_box_id',
                __('Citation', WE_DOMAIN),
                [$this, 'we_view_editor'],
                'post',
                'advanced',
                'high'
            );
        }

        public function we_view_editor($post)
        {
            wp_nonce_field('we_remote', 'nonce_editor');
            $citaiton = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wp_textarea_citation', true);
            wp_editor(
                $citaiton,
                'citation_box_text_id',
                [
                    'wpautop'           => true,
                    'media_buttons'     => false,
                    'textarea_name'     => 'wp_textarea_citation',
                    'textarea_rows'     => 30,
                    'teeny'             => true,
                    'quicktags'         => true,
                    'drag_drop_upload ' => true,
                ]
            );
        }

        public function we_save_mb($post_id)
        {
            if (!isset($_POST['nonce_editor']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce_editor'], 'we_remote')) :
                return $post_id;
            endif;

            if (!current_user_can('manage_options', $post_id)) :
                return $post_id;
            endif;

            if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) :
                return $post_id;
            endif;

            if (isset($_POST['wp_textarea_citation'])) :
                $wp_editor = sanitize_text_field($_POST['wp_textarea_citation']);
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'wp_textarea_citation', wp_kses_post($wp_editor));
            endif;
        }
    }

endif;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero estas haciendo sanitize_text_field!!!! sabes que hace eso???

Comment: Creo que tu error está en sanitize_text_field() esto elimina todo el formato html y deja solo el texto plano.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jefferzon Bol, efectivamente era eso, Nuevamente gracias.